# pointer to structure and self pointers

Tags: c, algorithm, pointers, structure

What is the difference between self referential pointer in structure and pointer to structure?

```
    struct abc
    {
    int data;
    struct abc *next;
    }
    struct abc *pt;
```

1. What are the differences between `*next` and `*pt`??
2. How they differ in their use??

I am really in doubt between these two

I am a beginner

First example is used mainly for linked list

Are pointer to structure node and self referential pointer the same thing?

[please see](http://see-programming.blogspot.in/2013/05/chain-hashing-separate-chaining-with.html)

see-programming.blogspot.in/2013/05/chain-hashing-separate-chaining-with.html here we have used struct hash *hashTable as an array ..how?? and can we do same with *pt

Comment: There is no difference; they are both just pointers to `struct abc` objects.  Any difference is only how they are used (and you haven't shown any code that uses them, so there's not much to say here...)

Comment: what difference does pointer to a structure within structure and outside it means,,can u please give example where they both work differently or they behave in same way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. **They are of the same type. They behave in the exact same way.**

   Some example usage:

   ```
   // declare 2 structs
   struct abc s1;
   struct abc s2;

   // point pt to s1
   pt = &s1;

   // point s1.next to s2
   s1.next = &s2;

   // access pt->data
   int a = pt->data;

   // access s1.next->data
   int a = s1.next->data;
   ```
2. **Differences in usage:**

   - There's only one `pt` variable.
   - For every `struct abc` variable, there is a `next` variable.

   In the context of a linked-list, there is only one head pointer, thus `pt` would be it.
   But each node points to the next node, thus `next` should be used for this.
3. **Using pointers as arrays?**

   Yes, this can be done with either `pt` or `next`.

   A pointer just points to an address in memory. There can be any number of structs following on each other at that location.

   If you want to use it as an array (or just using pointers in general), you just have to make sure you don't try to access elements that you didn't allocate memory for (with `malloc` for example) and free the memory after usage (if you used `malloc`).

   Some example usage with array:

   ```
   // declare a struct
   struct abc s1;

   // make an array of size 10
   struct abc *a1 = malloc(10*sizeof(struct abc));

   // give the 4th element a new value
   a1[4] = s1;

   // free the memory
   free(a1);
   ```

I hope that helps a bit.

Comment: what difference does pointer to a structure within structure and outside it means,,can u please give example where they both work differently or they behave in same way

Comment: see-programming.blogspot.in/2013/05/chain-hashing-separate-chaining-with.html here we have used struct hash *hashTable  as an array ..how?? and can we do same with *pt

Comment: do we need to free the array

Comment: and yeah while declaring nodes like a tree node or a linked list node do we need to allocate space for it using malloc??cant we declare it like we declare int??

Comment: @ayushnigam We also need to use `malloc` to allocate space for linked-list or tree nodes. If we try to do it without it, we'll inevitably end up trying to access a variable that's gone out of scope, which is [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually, very little difference at all.

1. `next` is a member of the same structure it is pointing to.  `pt` is not a member of the structure it is pointing to.
2. They are used in a similar way, except that to use `next` you have a have an existing `struct abc`, and `pt` can be used directly.  Please consider:

```
    myABC.next= &myOtherABC ;
    pt= &myOtherABC ;
```

> are pointer to structure node and self referential pointer same thing

They are and they are not.  Depends on point of view.  They **are** because they both point to a structure.  They are **not** because a `pointer to structure` can point to any structure, and as a variable it can be a parameter, a local variable, a member of another `struct`, etc.  But a `self referential pointer` is necessarily a member of a `struct` and points to the same `struct` it is a member of.

Comment: see-programming.blogspot.in/2013/05/chain-hashing-separate-chaining-with.html here we have used struct hash *hashTable as an array ..how?? and can we do same with *pt

Answer (score 1):

The only difference applies to people that write compilers. That is because a self-referential pointer refers to itself before itself is fully declared.  So someone writing a compiler has to deal with this special case.

As a programmer (that means *you*), there is no difference, and the terms do not offer any additional meaning.

Answer (score 0):

1. they are the same type but they do not contain the same value
2. from pt you can access next because pt point to a structure that contain next. but from next you can't access pt.

for linked list, you have to understand, that the list contain at the begining 1 element, and this element know how reach the next element of the list, it is the goal of the next pointer

Comment: do we need to allocate the memory using malloc for any structure??cant we declare it like declaring int

Comment: you can declare it like an int. like that : struct abc variable;
 // variable is the name

Comment: then while creating a node why do we allocate space by malloc ??

Comment: there are two ways, etheir you declare it from a pointer with malloc or you declare it 'like an int' it is the same result, the malloc as the advantage that you can free it when you will not need it anymore

Comment: free it does what benefit to me??

Comment: in this case nothing but if the structure was bigger it will let you say to the Os "I no  longer need this memory you can use it for anything else"

Answer (score 0):

There is **no** difference between those two pointers.

A possible difference in usage depends on the context **but still does not apply to their nature of being both pointer to the same type of structure** and therefore undergoing the same rules in terms of assignment, reading and arithmetics.

Comment: can u please tell difference in usage??

Comment: @ayushnigam: I can't, as the usage is the code and I see to few sources to know the code.

Comment: see-programming.blogspot.in/2013/05/chain-hashing-separate-chaining-with.html here we have used struct hash *hashTable as an array ..how?? and can we do same with *pt

Comment: @ayushnigam: `struct hash *` is not the same as `struct node *`. I do not see how the linked code is related to the code you show us (at least not in the way `strcut hash *` is used).