# Self Referential Pointer in c

Tags: c, pointers

**Can someone shed some light on self-referential pointer**. Self-referential data types are the types containing the pointer or reference to their own kind but i want know about self-referential pointer. Can you please explain the term with some code.

Any links/resources to learn more about this would also be highly helpful.

Edit1:

Can you explain this:

> The only self-referential pointer would be a `void *`

And also there is this code which confuses me more:

> `int *p = (int*) &p;`

Comment: You'll need to be more specific about what you're asking. It's trivial to do `void* p = &p`, but I assume you're asking about something more complex (and less useless).

Comment: You seem to refer to a term ("self-referential pointer") you have read or heard somewhere. Could you refer to that source to give some context?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39151133/what-is-self-referencing-pointer-in-c

Comment: @Sneftel i want to know more about the term self-referential-pointer and nothing complex

Comment: @Yunnosch https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39151133/what-is-self-referencing-pointer-in-c this also has the same title

Comment: @rimiro The term "self referential pointer" does not have a widely used meaning other than a self-referential type.

Comment: @rimiro The question you linked seems to explain it pretty well.  What *specifically* about it are you having trouble understanding?

Comment: In the `int *p = (int *) &p;`, the cast is necessary because `&p` has the type `int **` which is not compatible with `int *`, but the cast tells the compiler "I know what I'm doing".  The `void *p; p = &p;` example also features a type conversion, but any data pointer type can be converted to `void *` without cast.  The type of `&p` is `void **`, but the implicit conversion to `void *` is permitted by C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct a *self referencing* pointer this way:

```
void *p = &p;
```

`p` is a generic pointer that points to itself.

The problem is you cannot dereference  this pointer without a cast to an actual pointer type. Here is code to demonstrate this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    void *p = &p;
    printf("p = %p\n", p);
    printf("*(void **)p = %p\n", *(void **)p);
    printf("*(void **)p %c= p\n", *(void **)p == p ? '=' : '!');
    return 0;
}
```

As commented by *Jonathan Leffler*, `void *p; p = &p;` features a type conversion, but any data pointer type can be converted to `void *` without a cast. The type of `&p` is `void **`, but the implicit conversion to `void *` is permitted by C.

There are also self referring types:

```
struct self { struct self *self; };
```

This structure is not very useful, it is a simple indirection, but you can initialize it in a self referring way:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct self { struct self *self; };

int main() {
    struct self s = { &s };
    struct self *p = &s;

    printf("p = %p\n", (void *)p);
    printf("p->self = %p\n", (void *)p->self);
    printf("p %c= p->self\n", p == p->self ? '=' : '!');
    return 0;
}
```

In both cases, `p` contains its own address, which can be interpreted as *`p` is self-referential*.

Comment: Note that the `void *p; p = &p;` example features a type conversion, but any data pointer type can be converted to `void *` without a cast.  The type of `&p` is `void **`, but the implicit conversion to `void *` is permitted by C.

Comment: "Self-referential data types are the types containing the pointer or reference to their own kind" in the same way how would you define self-referential pointers.

Comment: @rimiro You're looking for knowledge where there is nothing to know. The only thing that would make a pointer "self-referential" is pointing to itself.

Answer (score 2):

Other than `void*`, there is no such thing as a self-referential pointer in C. That's because, if you were to write

```
foo* p;
foo* pp = &p;
```

where `pp` is a self-referential pointer, the *types* are not compatible, so compilation will fail. The only type for which compilation would pass is the case where `foo` is `void` and that's because you are allowed to convert a `void**` pointer to a `void*` pointer.

Really, you mean a *self-referential type*, such as can be found when implementing a linked list.

Comment: can you please explain the edit

Comment: @rimiro: Yes, `void*` is the exception. I've added that.